# Retrieve the record with the newest change per group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a table `locations`:

```
user | timestamp | state | other_data
-------------------------------------
1      100         1       some_data
1      200         1       some_data
1      300         0       some_data
1      400         0       some_data
2      100         0       some_data
2      200         0       some_data
```

This is for a location tracking app. A location has two `state`s (1 for "user is within range" and 0 for "user is out of range").

Now I want to retrieve the last time a user's location state has changed.
Example for `user` = 1

```
user | timestamp | state | other_data
-------------------------------------
1      300         0       some_data
```

Because this was the first location update that has the same `state` value as the "current" (`timestamp` 400) record.

Higher-level description: I want to display the user something like "You have been in / out of range since [timestamp]"

The faster the solution, the better of course

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag. Nevertheless, if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ranks to order the rows and then pick the `min` timestamp of the first ranked rows.

```
select user,min(timestamp) as timestamp,min(state) as state
from 
(select l.*,@rn:=case when @user=user and @state=state then @rn
                      when @user<>user then 1
                 else @rn+1 end as rnk
 ,@user:=user,@state:=state
 from locations l 
 cross join (select @rn:=0,@user:='',@state:='') r
 order by user,timestamp desc
) t
where rnk=1
group by user
```

Comment: Works like a charm even though quite long... thank you! Will accept in a few days if there aren't any faster or shorter solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*
from locations l
where l.timestamp = (select max(l2.timestamp)
                     from locations l2
                     where l2.user = l.user
                    );
```

For this to work well, you want an index on `locations(user, timestamp)`.

This can be faster than the `join` and `group by` approach.  In particular, the correlated subquery can make use of an index, but a `group by` on the whole table often does not (in MySQL).

Comment: This does not work. When I execute it, it returns the `1 | 400 | 0` set instead of `1 | 300 | 0` as in my example result

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the only way to achieve this is a sells join. Something a bit like;

```
 Select table.* From table
Inner Join
(Select id, max(timestamp) as tm from table group by id) as m
On m.tm = table.timestamp and m.id = table.id
```

Syntax is for MsSQL, it should transfer to MySQL though. Might have to specify column names instead of table.*

Comment: Does not work in MySQL, you need to specify what type of join it should be